# Consulta a firebase devuelve promesa pendiente - javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, promesas

traigo esta duda que me surgió cuando estaba intentando llamar un dato desde mi base de datos de firestore para poder guardar este dato en una variable. Sucede que cuando quiero imprimir mi variable en pantalla para comprobar que lo está retornando correctamente, me devuelve un "promise {pending}". Al principio creí que sería algo simple de solucionar pero me he dado cuenta que no consigo idear la forma de solucionar esto.

```
let db = firebase.firestore();

let miDato = db.collection("infoUsuarios").doc("C1S90auTbucRA7V2UiqdmdE5u133")
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.data().Peso); //este console log SI me devuelve mi valor
        return doc.data().Peso;       //pero al retornarlo, esto me devolvera una promesa
    })

console.log(miDato); //esto me devuelve promise pending
```

Esto es lo que me devuelve mi consola, como se ve, al final está incluido el valor que estoy solicitando (78), pero por decirlo de una forma, no se como sacarlo de ahí.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El método `then` devuelve una promesa. Si queres obtener el dato, podes usar [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Answer (score 2):

Debes usar `async/await` para poder obtenerlo, el `async/await` lo que hará es que a la hora de procesar una promesa, va a esperar a que termine la ejecución de la misma, es por ello, que debes usarlo.

Lo que pasa con tu código es que se está ejecutando la sentencia y mientras se ejecuta se pinta el console.log, ya que `javascript` es asíncrono, por lo tanto, al especificarlo con `async/await` el flujo de ejecución se convierte en síncrono, tu código debería ser algo así:

```javascript
(async () => {
  let db = firebase.firestore();

  let miDato = await 
  db.collection("infoUsuarios").doc("C1S90auTbucRA7V2UiqdmdE5u133")
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.data().Peso); //este console log SI me devuelve mi valor
        return doc.data().Peso;
    });

  console.log(miDato);
})();
```

Si tienes alguna función que este ejecutando ese código debes ponerle la palabra reservada, `async`, algo parecido a esto:

```javascript
async function myrequest() {
  let db = firebase.firestore();

  let miDato = await 
  db.collection("infoUsuarios").doc("C1S90auTbucRA7V2UiqdmdE5u133")
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.data().Peso); //este console log SI me devuelve mi valor
        return doc.data().Peso;
  });

  console.log(miDato);
}
```

o con funciones flechas así:

```javascript
const myRequest = async () => {
  let db = firebase.firestore();

  let miDato = await 
  db.collection("infoUsuarios").doc("C1S90auTbucRA7V2UiqdmdE5u133")
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.data().Peso); //este console log SI me devuelve mi valor
        return doc.data().Peso;
  });

  console.log(miDato); 
}
```